# Restrict which properties are binded using BindProperty on a class

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

```
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Test.Code" />
    <input asp-for="Test.Hash" disabled="disabled" />
</form>

public class Test
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Hash { get; set; }
}


public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Test { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say i only want the property Code to be binded, the user can remove the disabled from hash on browser tools. How can i tell this on server side to accept only certain properties?

Comment: that's basically the same no? user can remove this with javascript, but readonly allows the property to be binded. What i need is the property to not be binded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're referring to is called Over-Posting.

[Preventing mass assignment or over posting in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/preventing-mass-assignment-or-over-posting-in-asp-net-core/)

Excerpt:

> 1. Use BindAttribute on the action method

```
public IActionResult Safe1([Bind(nameof(UserModel.Name))] UserModel model)
{
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

> 2. Use [Editable] or [BindNever] on the model

```
public class UserModel
{
    [MaxLength(200)]
    [Display(Name = "Full name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Editable(false)]
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

> 3. Use two different models

```
public class BindingModel
{
    [MaxLength(200)]
    [Display(Name = "Full name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserModel
{
    [MaxLength(200)]
    [Display(Name = "Full name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Editable(false)]
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

> 4. Use a base class

```
public class BindingModel
{
    [MaxLength(200)]
    [Display(Name = "Full name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserModel : BindingModel
{
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

> 5. Use ModelMetadataTypeAttribute

```
[ModelMetadataType(typeof(UserModel))]
public class BindingModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserModel
{
    [MaxLength(200)]
    [Display(Name = "Full name")]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Razorpages, can i use this bind on a handler method?

Comment: There is only one default model binder, so I don't know how it could be different for any core technology.